# How to convert Excel formula to Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

This code calculates a sum of string lengths in the range `H1:V5` using `G` as a row index and `C` as a column index. It works perfectly in Excel:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT(LEN(INDEX(H1:V5,N(IF({1},ROW(G2:G5))),N(IF({1},C2:C5+1))))*ISNUMBER(G2:G5))}
```

[image]

But when I try it in Google Sheets it doesn't work although Google Sheets recognizes all commands. Is it possible to convert my formula to Google Sheets? Or maybe there is some workaround to get the same result there?

Open with Google Sheets returns incorrect result:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(ARRAYFORMULA(SUMPRODUCT(LEN(INDEX(H1:V5,N(IF({1},ROW(G2:G5))),N(IF({1},C2:C5+1))))*ISNUMBER(G2:G5))), 1, 1)
```

Comment: Try uploading the Excel spreadsheet into Googledocs. I would presume it would convert it for you to any alternate syntax automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the construct index...n(if({1}... is peculiar to Excel.

The vlookup function in Google sheets is very versatile and you can use that instead:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(len(vlookup(row(H1:K5),{row(H1:K5),H1:K5},C1:C5+2,false))*isnumber(G1:G5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Does it have to be `=ArrayFormula(sumproduct...)`?

Comment: I like the phrase: `very versatile`. Seems to be true :))

Comment: As far as I know sumproduct behaves in much the same way in Google Sheets as in Excel - in this case you would have the option of using ArrayFormula(sum(... like in Excel but I wanted to try and get as close as possible to the original Excel formula.